# PowerShell to Export SharePoint Sites and Subsides with security groups

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, export-to-csv, sharepoint-online, sites

I'm attempting to come up with a powershell script that would allow me to export a list of sites and subsites and the permission groups there in to a CSV.

I'm familiar with using the cmdlts but not building whole scripts. 
 I'm able to use:

```
Get-SPOSiteGroup  | Export-CSV C:\...
```

To export site groups to a CSV but it doesn't include the name of the sites they are in.

I also found a script online that would print out the sites and subsite in my site collection here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online

I'm not sure how to marry the information. I'm trying to export to a CSV a list of sites and subsites and the security groups there in.

I try to run:

```
get-sposite | Get-SPOSiteGroup **webdite**
```

And get this error message:

> "Get-SPOSiteGroup : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters
>   for the command either because the command does not take pipeline
>   input or the input and its properties do not match  any of the
>   parameters that take pipeline input"

I'm not sure how to get all of this to work together.

Answer (score 1):

[`Get-SPOSiteGroup` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spositegroup?view=sharepoint-ps) accepts `Site` parameter, so site groups per every *site collection* within a tenant could be retrieved like this:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl 
$sitesInfo = Get-SPOSite 

#Retrieve and print all sites
foreach ($site in $sitesInfo) {
    Write-Host 'Site collection:' $site.Url     
    Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site.Url
    Write-Host '-----------------------------' 
}
```

---

To retrieve in addition groups per every *web site*, the following script could be utilized:

```
$adminUrl = "https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com"
$UserName = "<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "--password goes here--"

$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$pscreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $SecurePassword

Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $pscreds
$sitesInfo = Get-SPOSite 

foreach ($site in $sitesInfo) {
    Write-Host 'Site collection:' $site.Url     
    #1. Retrieve and print site info 
    #Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site.Url
    $AllWebs = Get-SPOWebs -Url $site.Url -Credential $creds

    #2.Retrieve and print webs info (groups Title property in this case)
    foreach ($web in $AllWebs) {
        $web.Context.Load($web.RoleAssignments.Groups)
        $web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
        $web.RoleAssignments.Groups.GetEnumerator() | % { Write-Host $_.Title }   
    }
    Write-Host '-----------------------------' 
}
```

**Key points**:

1. to retrieve webs within a site collection [`Get-SPOWebs.ps1`](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/eb70dc6f1b6d4510c8eea630ef990ac3) is utilized
   here
2. to get groups *per web site* `Web.RoleAssignments.Groups` is used